# array_push is replacing the variables instead of adding them to the end

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-push

```
array_push($info["First_Names"], "$fname");
array_push($info["Last_Names"], "$lname");
array_push($info["Gender"], "$gender");
```

Does anyone see an issue? Array push is just replacing variables instead of adding them. The variables of `$fname`, `$lname`, and `$gender` are defined by the user in a form. I want the variables to simply be added to the end of the array instead of being replaced. Any responses are appreciated.

Comment: Is `$info["First_Names"]` actually an array? And you keep saying "array", singular, but surely each of `$info['First_Names']`, `$info['Last_Names']` and `$info['Gender']` are individual arrays?

Comment: To put what meagar said in a different way, are you trying to put these values into `$info` or  a two dimensional array like `$info['First_Names']`?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention; Info is an array,first/lastnames and gender are all arrays in info, multidemensional array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `$info["First_Names"]` ,`$info["Last_Names"]` ,`$info["Gender"]` are arrays ,I don't see any problem .

```
$info = array();

$info["First_Names"] = array();
$info["Last_Names"] = array();
$info["Gender"] = array();

$fname = 'Fname1';
$lname = 'Lname1';
$gender = 'M';

array_push( $info["First_Names"] ,$fname );
array_push( $info["Last_Names"] ,$lname );
array_push( $info["Gender"] ,$gender );

$fname = 'Fname2';
$lname = 'Lname2';
$gender = 'F';

array_push( $info["First_Names"] ,$fname );
array_push( $info["Last_Names"] ,$lname );
array_push( $info["Gender"] ,$gender );

var_dump( $info );
```

Outputs :

```
array (size=3)
  'First_Names' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Fname1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Fname2' (length=6)
  'Last_Names' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'Lname1' (length=6)
      1 => string 'Lname2' (length=6)
  'Gender' => 
    array (size=2)
      0 => string 'M' (length=1)
      1 => string 'F' (length=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[From the manual:](https://www.php.net/array_push)

`Note: If you use array_push() to add one element to the array it's better to use $array[] = because in that way there is no overhead of calling a function.`

e.g.

```
<?php

$info["First_Names"][] = $fname;
$info["Last_Names"][] = $lname;
$info["Gender"][] = $gender;

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative is use a function.

```
<?php
function add_in_key_array($array, $key, $value){
 $array[$key][] = $value;
}
?>
```